# how to archive the Items and folders in document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library

I have a requirement like below.

our document library consists of nearly 5000 documents (some of the documents are inside folders,sub folders and sub sub folders also)

our customer asked a way to archive all his files after certain amount of time.....

let us say for 1 year. They want to have an archival document library similar to the existing library. after 1 year, they want **only folders to be present in the existing document library** and files to be moved to archival document library addressing to the same folders and sub folders in archival document library.

so that they can start uploading new files on the existing document library next year.

My environment is SharePoint 2013. Is there any out of box solution that matches my requirement.

Please give me an idea of how to start and what to start or is it possible in any ways???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at in-place record management. Basically, you will need to define a retention policy that will execute a certain action after 1 year. The actions could be, move the document to a different location, declare it as record, remove it, and others.

Take a look at [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261982.aspx) link for more information.

-Hope it helps.

Comment: I am marking workflow option for my requirement...

Answer (score 0):

a list can have millions of record, issue is with view, so if we create a subfolders and move data in subfolders, then we should be good. we can write ps to do this, let me know if more details are required.